# let '=' operator of a certain class run the constructor upon declaration

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I want to know if there's a way to make the = operator trigger the constructor (or any method) of a class upon its declaration

let's say

```
class foo
{
public:
string variable="";
foo(string var)
{
    this->variable=var;
}
foo(){}
void operator=(string var)
{
    this->variable=var;
}
} 
int main()
{
foo obj="new foo object";
}
```

When I run that, it says "error: conversion from 'const char[15]' to non-scalar type 'foo' requested"

But when I do this

```
foo obj;
obj="new foo object";
```

It works

What can I do so the first method will work?

Comment: Provide a constructor that accepts a `const char *` argument, and uses it to initialise `variable`.    Also (1) look up use of initialiser lists in constructors rather than assigning members in the constructor body and (2)  it is often considered better technique to have `operator=()`  have a return type `foo &` rather than `void`, and to return `*this`.

Comment: Your uses of `this` are completely superfluous.

Comment: Sorry I got used to using "this" because I came from another programming language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can I do so the first method will work?

Provide a constructor that takes an argument of type `char const *`.

And use the initialization list of the constructors to initialize members, not assignments in the constructors body.

BTW:

> `foo obj = "new foo object";`

does NOT call `operator=()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the constructor (that should be declared as explicit anyway, so the construct you want is actually bad practice IIRC)?
Just do:

```
foo obj("bar");
```

Also variable should not have a default empty value, the default constructor will create it properly.
You should also put `variable` in the initializer list.

Comment: I already fixed the default empty value and passed it to the constructor